# conda command fails after anaconda installation

Tags: python, windows, installation, anaconda3

After installing Anaconda in Windows I get the following error when trying to use it:

- conda command

:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mohamed\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

- anaconda command

:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mohamed\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from binstar_client.scripts.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'binstar_client'
```

I tried to delete and reinstall anaconda several times but useless

Comment: Look here: https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/installing-anaconda-windows , more specifically: How to Add Anaconda to Path (Optional)